# How can I use an algorithm2e function macro inside an algorithm2e caption?

Tags: algorithm2e

Algorithm2e lets you define functions using `\SetKwFunction{Fn}{Function}` which you can then reference anywhere in the document (not just in an `algorithm` environment) using e.g. `\Fn` (which will output `Function` all nicely typeset in the right font). However, this doesn't work inside captions. For example, the following doc:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\SetKwFunction{Fn}{Function}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{\Fn, my function}
  \KwRet{0}\;
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

dies with

```
Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6   \caption{\Fn, my function}
```

Anyone know what's going on, and how to fix it?

Comment: `\caption{\protect\Fn my function}` should work.

Comment: That did work. If you make this a comment an answer, I'll mark it as correct  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro has to be protected that it can be used inside `caption`:

```
\caption{\protect\Fn my function}
```

For more information why this is needed have a look at this question:

[What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands)